Primefaces Autocomplete Converter similar to omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter
I am working on a web application using primefaces. I have an autocomplete field that gets its value from a pojo object. I would like to know if there is a converter solution similar to omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter so that I can avoid implementing my own converter.
The omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter iterates through the SelectItem collection of the SelectItems component in order to determine the actual pojo value. Is there a similar way to iterate through the AutoComplete suggestions (or only selected value) to determine the selected pojo value?

You need the omnifaces.ListConverter instead. There's an example in showcase https://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/ListConverter

In the example the converter is defined as follows:
<o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{autoCompleteBean.availableEntities}" />
In my use case, I have my completeMethod perform a database query and fetch the autocomplete suggestions. As a result, the converter's list must be dynamic. I came up with a solution of storing these suggestions on a list on the backing bean, in order to keep the pojos as well, and pass that list to the converter, but I am not sure this is the intended way to do the job...

Why not just use the OmniFaces converter?  If not then YES you have to create your own converter for POJO's as that is how JSF/Faces works.
There is this open PF ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/10231 which discusses possible adding the same AutoConverter as OmniFaces but it has not been implemented yet.
